# Undefined number of viewcontrollers

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create an app which supports directories. I have a UITableView which has a list of directories as cells. When a directory is pressed, I can perform a segue to a childviewcontroller that I've defined in StoryBoard that uses the same .h and .m as Parent. My question is as follows:

How can I create an unlimited number of childviewcontrollers?

i.e parent -> child -> child ... -> child

Edit:

Jason, my understanding of your design is as follows:

```
UINavigationController 
         -> UIViewController 
             -> UITableViewController 
                  -> UITableViewController -> ... -> UITableViewController
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I create an unlimited number of childviewcontrollers?

Assuming you are using a `UINavigationController`, you can continue to push view controllers onto the stack (until you run out of memory).

I would create a single UITableViewController subclass (e.g. `FileListingTableViewController`) and continually recreate this object.

You can maintain the relationship between parent and child at a *model* level. The *controller* can handle behavior simply by checking if the selected cell model *hasChildren*. If so, push another `FileListingTableViewController` otherwise, push another view controller. This keeps the *view* dumb so you don't need parent/child objects.

Comment: edited my question, does my diagram accurately represent what you're saying? Thanks!

Comment: No. I am suggesting using a `UINavigation` controller and continually push `FileListingTableViewController` onto the stack for directories.

Comment: Why is that more efficient than pushing UIViewControllers with UITableView's inside them?

Comment: Didn't say it was. Whatever, ViewController you want to use is fine. I suggest UITableViewController. But you know your app best. My main point, is there is no need for *parent*/*child* versions of the controller.

Comment: I agree with Jason, UINavigationController is perfect for a drill down situation. All you would need to do is pass the directory object to the controller, let it display all of its children and then push that view controller onto the navigation controller. This would be much easier to develop and maintain.